# Facing encoding problem in angular in url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

chrome is encoding the url. anyone know any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting in the dedicated room you explained to me your need and here is the final solution, which is the simplest you can find :

```js
    const params = { 'userId[]': [1, 2, 3] };

    const paramStr = Object.entries(params)
      .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value.join(',')}`)
      .join('&');

    this.http.get('http://www.test.com?' + paramStr).subscribe();
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2ugoye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (Open the network dev tools)

Other solutions involve rewriting an encoder and providing it to the http module. I'm not a fan of that, when you can just use a one liner to do the same thing.

Comment: please save your stackblitz. not able to see code

Comment: Sorry, edited it

Comment: please check chat

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class AppComponent {
  codec = new HttpUrlEncodingCodec();
  name = 'Angular';
  baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const params = { 'userId[]': 1 };
    this.http
      .get(this.baseUrl + 'posts', { params })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.name = this.name.concat(data[0].title);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not working. in chrome, it is working same, it is working fine only in firefox

Comment: And `{ userId: [1] }` ?

Comment: I need [] character in key like userId[]

Comment: @techguy please try, see the result. I would explain the syntax to you right now, but if it does not work, there's no point.

Comment: if forming the url : posts?userId=1 , I need posts?userId[]=1

Comment: Did you correctly write it with `[1]` and not `1` ?

Comment: yes I wrote this:   const params: any = { userId: [1] };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248447/discussion-between-techguy-and-mgx).